analysis the magnitude of fft of square pulse
It is pretty straightforward to scale the amplitude of fft's results by multiplying 2/Nfft (loosely speaking) to get the correct amplitude of signal components (except for the DC component), where Nfft is the number of fft bins.
However, when it comes to a squared pulse, multiplying 2/Nfft fails to yield the correct amplitude of the sinc function. The correct way to scale it is to multiply sampling interval.
Why is that?

Note that usually you would normalize not by the number of frequency bins $\tt{N_{FFT}}$ but by the non-zero padded input time domain sequence $N$. If you’re not zero-padding, $\tt{N_{FFT}} = N$
